# Is Date 1985-01-01T00:00:00 Greater Than

Tags: php, date, datetime

If the date from the SQL database comes back as:

`1985-01-01T00:00:00`

How can I check to see if that date is `>` 2016-05-01 ? I've tried:

```
if ( $house['date_sold'] > new DateTime("2016-05-01 00:00:00") ) {
```

To no avail...

Comment: `if ( new DateTime($house['date_sold']) > new DateTime("2016-05-01") ) {   }`

Comment: What is `$house['date_sold']`?  I'm assuming it's a string.  You're gonna want to create a `new DateTime` object out of it.